# Regex to extract valid Http or Https

Tags: java, regex

I'm currently having some issues with a regex to extract a URL.

I want my regex to take URLS such as:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
https://stackoverflow.com
http://local:1000
https://local:1000
```

Through some tutorials, I've learned that this regex will find all the above: `^(http|https)\://.*$` however, it will also take `http://local:1000;http://invalid` `http://khttp://`as a single string when it shouldn't take it at all.

I understand that my expression isn't written to exclude this, but my issue is I cannot think of how to write it so it checks for this scenario.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Looking at my issue, it seems that I could eliminate my issue as long as I can implement a check to make sure '//' doesn't occur in my string after the initial http:// or https://, any ideas on how to implement?

Sorry this will be done with Java

I also need to add the following constraint: a string such as `http://local:80/test:90` fails because of the duplicate of port...aka I need to have a constraint that only allows two total : symbols in a valid string (one after http/s) and one before port.

Comment: You want to extract the url without the protocol?

Comment: Hi, if the string contains multiple urls such as http://http://k.http://blah it shouldn't be found as valid in my regex

Comment: Yes, as long as it's not another URL it's fine.

Comment: Looking at my issue, it seems that I could eliminate my issue as long as I can implement a check to make sure '//' doesn't occur in my string after the initial http:// or https://, any ideas on how to implement?

Comment: Please read the [regex] tag's description: "Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only produce a match if if there is no `://` after its first appearance in the string.

```
^https?:\/\/(?!.*:\/\/)\S+
```

Note that trying to parse a valid url from within a string is very complex, see
[In search of the perfect URL validation regex](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex), so the above does not attempt to do that.
It will just match the protocol and following non-space characters.

In Java

```
Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("^https?:\\/\\/(?!.*:\\/\\/)\\S+");
Matcher m = reg.matcher("http://somesite.com"); 
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
} else {
    System.out.println("No match");
}
```

Comment: Seems like this is what I need, any idea how to do this in java?

Comment: @Greg. Yes, that's great, but it assumes that you have already got the url.

Comment: Mike- Thank you, this works great.  One question, if I wanted to add into the contraints that a second colon in the string also makes it invalid (Ex: "https://local:800/test:5") how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @user2019260. If you mean a _third_ colon, you could use `^https?:\\/\\/(?!.*:(.*:|\\/\\/))\\S+` This will disallow `://` or two `:` in the string after `http://`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your programming language to see if it already has a parser. E.g. php has parse_url()

Answer (score 0):

From http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

This may change based on the programming language/tool

Answer (score 0):

```
/[A-Za-z]+://[A-Za-z0-9-]+.[A-Za-z0-9-:%&;?#/.=]+/g
```